# How to skip the signUp activity and proceed to the homescreen in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have Profile class where the user enters his name and email. but whenever I open the app it asks the user to enter name. how do I skip this and make it show it to the user only once. I can use the `if username != null` method but every time user opens app it fetches data from database which makes the app slower. so how do I make the app show the profile activity only the first time and from the 2nd time he should be taken directly to the home screen.

Please help... Thanks in advance

```
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setup_profile);
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    progress = new ProgressDialog(this);

    input_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    input_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    input_status = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.status);
    input_quote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quote);
    input_ph = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_phone_number);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    addData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("com.your.package", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    boolean hasUsername = sp.getBoolean("has_username", false);

    if (hasUsername) { //checks if the user already input username to skip this activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(SetUpProfile.this, HomeScreen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    FirebaseUser user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user.getPhoneNumber());



    addData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            SetUpProfileHelper user;
            user = new SetUpProfileHelper(input_name.getText().toString(), input_email.getText().toString(), input_status.getText().toString(), input_quote.getText().toString());
            ref.child("Name").setValue(input_name.getText().toString());
            ref.child("Email").setValue(input_email.getText().toString());
            ref.child("Status").setValue(input_status.getText().toString());
            ref.child("Quote").setValue(input_quote.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Profile Successfully Updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(SetUpProfile.this, HomeScreen.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
            SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("com.appmaster.akash.messageplus", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

            editor.putBoolean("has_username", true); //save that the user enters username

            editor.apply();
        }
    });
```

Comment: No dude... first i hav a phone number auth activity... there i used this. after the user gets verified he's going to come to this profile activity. i want to skip this profile acitivity directly without fetching from database. how do i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Shared Preferences**.

Upon input of the username, when the user click button to next, call this:

```
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("com.your.package", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();

editor.putBoolean("has_username", true); //save that the user enters username

editor.apply();
```

And on your `ProfileActivity onCreate()`:

```
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("com.your.package", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

boolean hasUsername = sp.getBoolean("has_username", false);

if (hasUsername) { //checks if the user already input username to skip this activity
   Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, YourNextActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
   finish();
}
```

Comment: Error... 
http://ibb.co/fg9Bbw
on the line SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("com.your.package", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
i replaced it with my package name... still nullpointrexception

Comment: If you're calling this on an `activity`, you don't need to put the `context` on `context.getSharedPreferences(...`

Comment: Still not working... im getting the profile class again

Comment: Can you show your code? So we can fix it. Thanks.

Comment: look at my edited question...

Comment: Replace your `SharedPreferences` code above with the key, "com.appmaster.akash.messageplus". It seems that you've changed it below when you're writing but you forgot to change it on the fetching side.

Comment: shit.... omg tysm fr d code...

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preference for store the boolean value. Once user signed in change the boolean state, Next time check that boolean value before executing your code

Comment: can i get the code please?

Comment: Please provide a code when answering, also your answer is my answer below. You can maybe update/modify it if you find anything wrong. So we can avoid redundancy.