# how to save a function into sharedpreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, showcaseview

i want to save this view case into shared preference, so it will displayed only first time when apps running, here my code :

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_contact, menu);

    new Handler().postDelayed(
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mFancyShowCaseView = new FancyShowCaseView.Builder(ContactTabActivity.this)
                        .focusOn(findViewById(R.id.item_sync)) // ActionBar menu item id
                        .focusCircleRadiusFactor(1.5)
                        .customView(R.layout.case_view_sync, new OnViewInflateListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onViewInflated(@NonNull View view) {
                                view.findViewById(R.id.btnOke).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                        mFancyShowCaseView.removeView(); // this doesn't work
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }).closeOnTouch(false)
                        .build();
                       mFancyShowCaseView .show();
            }
        }, 50
);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

}

Comment: You don't want to try to save a "function", or a "view case". Simply save a `boolean` flag to indicate whether this is the first run, and only show your `FancyShowCaseView` if it is.

Comment: I guess this question is asked many times here on stackoverflow, you could also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457952/how-to-skip-the-signup-activity-and-proceed-to-the-homescreen-in-android/48458050#48458050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't save function but you can save logic which will stop functions  execution as in

```
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     pref = getSharedPreferences(this,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     editor = pref.edit();
    if(pref.getBoolean("isFirstTime",true){   // default true for first time

     editor.putBoolean("isFirstTime",false).commit(); //<-- update  so it will false ever after
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_contact, menu);

    new Handler().postDelayed(
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mFancyShowCaseView = new FancyShowCaseView.Builder(ContactTabActivity.this)
                        .focusOn(findViewById(R.id.item_sync)) // ActionBar menu item id
                        .focusCircleRadiusFactor(1.5)
                        .customView(R.layout.case_view_sync, new OnViewInflateListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onViewInflated(@NonNull View view) {
                                view.findViewById(R.id.btnOke).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View view) {
                                        mFancyShowCaseView.removeView(); // this doesn't work
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }).closeOnTouch(false)
                        .build();
                       mFancyShowCaseView .show();
            }
        }, 50
   );
  }
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: glad I could help :)